404 Error Not found after successful installation Magento
I am an aspiring Magento developer. As a beginner I had to install Magento 2 on my local machine using MAMP, and the composer in VSCODE.
I have just succesfully install Mangeto using the composer.
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <install-directory-name>

now also the installation using:
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/M241 \      
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=mangeto \
--db-user=root \   
--db-password=mypassword \
--admin-firstname=david \
--admin-lastname=olude \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=opensearch \
--opensearch-host=localhost \          
--opensearch-port=9200 \
--opensearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
--opensearch-timeout=15

-Now am using MAMP which I directed the web root to the pub further has suggested.
I also went into the config_core_data in the database and changed the URL to point to the pub.
-Afterwards I went ahead to run the following commands
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 0777 var/
sudo chmod -R 0777 generated/
sudo chmod -R 0777 pub/static/

This didn't solve the issue even after I have restarted my PC, thinking it will help.
so am still getting the same error when i navigate tot he base url: http://localhost/M241
I feel like am out of options here.
I also tried to flush cache:
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

what am I missing?

"Now am using MAMP which I directed the web root to the pub further has suggested." - by "directed", you mean you set the document root to the public directory? Then what would M241 in the URL be?

did you run bin magento indexer:reindex ?

If you are using windows, i advice to install it on WSL or docker instead,,
I had same issue when i try install magento on windows using XAMPP, my suggestion is to make a dedicated vhost and hostname for your app

add new hostname for your local dev
create new vhost for your store
this is example on xampp

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myshop/"
ServerName tokoku.loc

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/myshop/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
</Directory>

